# Exchange - No NDR

Tags: exchange-2007, ndr

I try to send a test email from my personal email account to a non-existent email in my company's domain.

I don't receive NDR at all. I'm under Exchange 07 SP1. Where can I configure it ?

Thx for your help guys.

Comment: Are you sure it is a nonexistent address? mycompany.ca is actually a real hostname with a real MX record. Secondly, the behavior you described is what would be expected since if you are inside and logged into the exchange server, you would be authenticated (but not if you are sending outside). Have you checked log files?

Comment: You may want to edit the 2nd question out and post it separately, to keep things from getting confused.

Comment: I edited, it seems that my second problem has just solved alone...

Comment: Bastien - no need to post additional duplicate questions.  When you edit your question to provide additional information, such as steps you've already taken to try to resolve the issue, your question will move to the top of the list.  I recommend you add this kind of information, allowing people to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that more and more anti-spam products these days are squashing these kinds of NDR's. Spammers will throw the whole dictionary at a company's email portal looking for bounce messages. The messages that don't generate NDRs are legit emails! Spammer gold! So it may not just be Exchange doing it, it could be an anti-spam setting somewhere.

Exchange 2007 can be configured to not send this kind of notice. Unfortunately, I'm not near my console so I can't look it up. Tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

mycompany.ca is a valid domain name and does exist, and can  recieve mail.

Comment: It's just an example ! I used the valid domain name of my company.